# Date/time values in Dlookup (MS Access 2010) VBA

Tags: date, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Is there a difference in the type of date/time values that access uses in Dlookup commands?

Example:
Table **tblreg** with multiple records, having clientname (string) and regstart (string)
Regstart is string but always uses the format dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm). This field can also have other values (depending on field typeindicator = <>T)
Query **qry1** points to table tblreg and contains **reg1:Cdate(regstart)** and typeindicator="T"

The controls RegStart and Regstop are defined as string variables (same reason as table)

VBA Code

```
Dim strOverlapClientName As String
Dim date1, date2 As Date
date1 = CDate(Me.RegStart)
date2 = CDate(Me.RegStop)
strOverlapClientName = DLookup("[ClientName]", 
                               "qryRegOverlap", 
                               "[Reg1]<= #" & date1 & "# AND [Reg2]>#" & date1 & "#")
```

Purpose: I want to query any existing clientname, where a new date/time registration overlaps an existing time registration of another client in the db.

Checked value: `05-10-2014 12:55`

Error: the DLookup function returns an error code 94 (Invalid use of Null)

Expected result should be 
a client having RegStart 05-10-2014 12:00:00 and Regstop 05-10-2014 13:00:00

Using a single criteria (e.g. "[Reg1]>= #" & date1 & "# ") does not throw an error, but returns a wrong record (02-01-2014 11:45:00)

What am I doing wrong here?

Art

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters. You need to declare all variables explicitly. Unlike other sophisticated programming languages, where you use

```
int numVar, someNum;
```

In VBA you should declare each variable by type. So

```
Dim date1 As Date, date2 As Date
```

The one you have will result in declaring date1 as Variant type and date2 as Date type.

Now, if the controls are Format as Dates the Cast **CDate** is not really required. In my opinion, the variables are not even required.

Next, JET engine deals date in American format, not the regular DD/MM/YYYY HH:NN:SS. So you need to format the dates accordingly.

Finally, If the condition is not met DLookup will yield a Null value. So You need to either use a Nz function or declare the variable as Variant.

```
Dim strOverlapClientName As String

strOverlapClientName = Nz(DLookup("[ClientName]", 
                                  "qryRegOverlap", 
                                  "[Reg1] <= " & Format(Me.RegStart, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy hh\:nn\:ss\#") & _
                                  " AND [Reg2] > " & Format(Me.RegStop, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy hh\:nn\:ss\#")), "No Value Found")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great!!!! This helped me out. The complete code how I now got it to work was slightly different, but the key elements in your answer did the trick.

Comment: Glad to help @Art, please feel free to mark this as answer and vote up so others could also be of benefit.